# Использование ROWNUM для создания уникального ключа

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть таблица T. При выборке из неё:

```
select t.* from t
```

Получаем:

```
  A      B
=============
  4      F
  9      S
  7      G
```

А при выборке:

```
    select rownum as rec_number, t.* from t order by A
```

Получим:

```
  REC_NUMBER     A      B
===========================
      1          4      F
      3          7      G
      2          9      S
```

Как бы нам получить:

```
  REC_NUMBER     A      B
===========================
      1          4      F
      2          7      G
      3          9      S
```

Без использования:

```
select rownum as rec_number, t2.* from 
    (select t.* from t order by A) t2
```

Comment: Ни как. только order by задает порядок записей, во всех остальных случаях мы не можем его гарантировать. А rownum в том же запросе, что и order by работает до него. можно использовать `row_number() over(order by A)` вместо rownum

Comment: Это то, что нужно, спасибо.  Именно `over(order by A)` я  не знаю. Вопрос мелкий, даже не знаю, следует ли оформить в форме ответа или удалить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ на основании совета @Mike

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY A) AS REC_NUMBER, T.* 
  FROM T 
  ORDER BY A
```